# Angularjs .scope() is undefined when called from <script> tag

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

Working with Angularjs for the first time.
MVC 4,
VS 2012

I have an angular function (AddRealTimeAlert) which can add an alert (nicely formatted div...not a generic js alert box) to be displayed to the user.  If the function is called using the button (see html below, #addAlertButton), the function works perfectly.  However, if the function is called by a script tag from the same html file or a different html file, it breaks.  Specifically, angular.element(alertsController).scope() returns null.  However, angular.element(alertsController) does not return null; it returns the div.  So that scope() method doesn't seem to work unless it's called from clicking the button.  Thoughts?

**HTML (_Alerts.cshtml)**:

```
<div id="alertsDiv">
    <div ng-controller="AlertsCtrl" id="alertsController">
        <div ng-repeat="alert in alertBasket.alerts()" class="alert-box radius {{alert.type}}">{{alert.message}}</div>
        <button class="btn" onclick="AddRealTimeAlert('my second alert!', 'success');" id="addAlertButton">Add Alert</button> //Clicking this does work!!
    </div>
</div>

<script>
        AddRealTimeAlert("my first alert!", "success"); //This does not work!!
</script>
```

**JS (alerts.js)**:

```
var alertModule = angular.module('rs-customer-portal', []);

alertModule.factory('alertBasket', function () {
    var alerts = [];
    var alertService = {};

    alertService.addAlert = function (alert) {
        alerts.push(alert);
    };

    alertService.alerts = function () {
        return alerts;
    };

    return alertService;

});

function AlertsCtrl($scope, alertBasket) {
    $scope.newAlert = {};
    $scope.alertBasket = alertBasket;
    $scope.msg = "my message";
}

function AddRealTimeAlert(newMessage, newType) {
    var newAlert = { message: newMessage, type: newType };

    alertsController = $('#alertsController');
    var scope = angular.element(alertsController).scope();

    scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.alertBasket.addAlert(newAlert);
    })
}
```

**Layout file excerpt(_Layout.cshtml):**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/_assets/RadioShack/lib/Angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/_assets/RadioShack/js/alerts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_Alerts"); }
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your in-page `<script>` comes before your `<script src="angular.js">`. Make sure angular.js is loaded first, and then your JS file and lastly your in-page script.

Another cause could be that sure Angular not has finished loading everything when your in-page script runs. It's possible that your call is invoked before Angular has inspected the DOM and created scopes and controller. Try this:

1. in you in-page block, add  `console.log("in-page script")`
2. in `AlertsCtrl`, add `console.log("loading controller")`
3. load the page and check the console

The correct order should be:

```
loading controller
in-page script
```

If it's not, then there is a loading order problem. Let me know the result and I'll try to help...

Comment: Thanks for the response Sylvain! I had similar thought.  Added _Layout html to question.  As you can see, I load angular.js first, then alerts.js and lastly the in-page script will be called when the partial (_Alerts.cshtml) is loaded.

Comment: We're on to something here...the order was incorrect: i.e. "in-page script" and then "loading controller".  Thoughts?

Just added a $(document).ready(function(){...} around the in-page script and that fixed it.  Is that good practice though?

Comment: I think DOM ready is unsafe here. The DOM might be ready, but that does not mean angular is done processing the DOM. There is no `Angular Ready` event. I read somewhere that if you use `$timeout`, then when angular is ready it'll process its queued $timeouts. But why use an in-page script like that? Can't you find a significant Angular event when you want that to happen such as "after the controller has been loaded" or "after the angular view has been loaded"?

Comment: We want to be able to (a) load alerts on page load and (b) show alerts based on what happens on a page (i.e. the user is filling out a form and they screw up a field or they're checking out their shopping cart but they item they're buying just sold out).  We want to throw an alert immediately, not wait to post back.  So, odds are that any event that throws an error would happen after the angularjs has already loaded, but it'd be nice to guarantee that in some way.  Maybe a retry policy of some sort on the scope call (i.e. if scope==null wait a second and try again)?

Comment: In the angular world, "page load" is not a very meaningful event. One solution could be to use the `$rootScope` to hold your `alertBasket`. This way you could use `myModule.run(function($rootScope){ $rootScope.alertBasket.addAlert(newAlert); })` in your in-page script. That way of doing ensures that everything is loaded before your code is executed. Your markup would then bind the alerts list to `$rootScpope. alertBasket` instead of to the controller's scope.

Comment: Earlier I wrote "There is no Angular Ready event". I was wrong; there is `angular.element().ready()` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element). I still think it's better if you can find another solution but I wanted to correct my statement.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you haven't disabled the debug info on your app:

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false)
```

According to the documentation, disabling the debug info limits the access to the .scope() functions.
See this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data